# How to Pass an ATL com object from c++ to c#

Tags: c#, c++, mfc, com, atl

using ATl i have created a com object called "Comptes" ,that has properties like name,username. this is the idl file for the atl project

```
import "oaidl.idl";
import "ocidl.idl";

[
    object,
    uuid(15297371-6D05-4466-B80D-26207555CD28),
    dual,
    nonextensible,
    pointer_default(unique)
]
interface Icompte : IDispatch{
    [propget, id(1)] HRESULT name([out, retval] BSTR* pVal);
    [propput, id(1)] HRESULT name([in] BSTR newVal);
    [propget, id(2)] HRESULT sername([out, retval] BSTR* pVal);
    [propput, id(2)] HRESULT sername([in] BSTR newVal);
    [propget, id(3)] HRESULT email([out, retval] BSTR* pVal);
    [propput, id(3)] HRESULT email([in] BSTR newVal);
    [propget, id(4)] HRESULT phone([out, retval] BSTR* pVal);
    [propput, id(4)] HRESULT phone([in] BSTR newVal);
};
[
    uuid(73A9DD4C-CE2D-4419-9F95-4A84C4E3B271),
    version(1.0),
]
library ATLOBJECTSLib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
    [
        uuid(1199A9AD-8AF7-4A25-A10B-DD06FB294B2E)      
    ]
    coclass compte
    {
        [default] interface Icompte;
    };
};
```

i have inculded the header and cpp file in an c++ mfc project and was able to estantiate the com object ,now in the mfc project i am sending data to c# project (just simple strings)
this the mfc part :

```
void CmfcappDlg::OnBnClickedCreateacountbutt()
{

    CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT::COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    Icompte* pcompte;

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_compte,nullptr,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_Icompte,(LPVOID*)&pcompte);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) 
    {
        namectrl.GetWindowText(name);
        sernamectrl.GetWindowText(sername);
        emailctrl.GetWindowText(email);
        phonectrl.GetWindowText(phone);
        
        pcompte->put_name(name.AllocSysString());
        pcompte->put_sername(sername.AllocSysString());
        pcompte->put_phone(phone.AllocSysString());
        pcompte->put_phone(email.AllocSysString());
        //Managed::showcswindow(name, sername);

    }

    CoUninitialize();
}
```

now i can send the dat to the c# part with this class :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Managed.h"
#using <System.dll>
using namespace System;
using namespace ::gettingdatafromc;

void Managed::showcswindow(CString name,CString sername)
{
    services::showwindow(gcnew String(name), gcnew String(sername));
}
```

and receive it in c# project with this class :

```
namespace gettingdatafromc
{
    public static class services
    {
        public static void showwindow(string name, string sername)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

everything works fine exept that i want to send the com object by passing it as a parameter to the showwindow method rather than a simple string to the c# project is this even dowable ,

Comment: You can pass a IWhatever (IUnknown derived) COM interface to methods (just like you do with BSTR like this: `[propget, id(1)] HRESULT blah([out, retval] IWhatever** pVal); [propput, id(1)] HRESULT blah([in] IWhatever* newVal);` or you can pass VARIANT like this: `[propget, id(1)] HRESULT blah([out, retval] VARIANT* pVal); [propput, id(1)] HRESULT blah([in] VARIANT newVal);` and wrap the object (IUnknown* or IDispatch*)  into the VARIANT

Comment: [COM interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/cominterop) and interop via C++/CLI are different technologies. It sounds like you want COM interop on top of C++/CLI interop, which would be rather odd. Pretty difficult to produce an answer without understanding the problem. What is it that you want?

Comment: Ensure the ATL project is built and registered.  In the C# project use Project > Add Reference > COM tab, select your ATL library.  You can now use ATLOBJECTSLib.Icompte as the method parameter type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to pass raw `IUnkown*` pointer to C# and then use `Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown` to convert `IntPtr` to `object` and then cast this object to `Icompte`. You will need to add reference to the corresponding TypeLib into C# project to be able to perform such a cast.

Comment: your method worked perfectly and i can receive the object in the c# and read its data ,now i have a problem modifying the objects properties i can read those properties but cannot modify them i get an error of |||(threw an exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException) Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt|||.

Comment: From the exception I can only say that most likely you have some problems with memory management in C++ implementation. Further diagnosis is only possible with full code available (or, even better, with some minimum reproducible sample).

Answer (score 0):

thank you for the kind reply , so i folowed your guidelines in the app i used a new showwindow2 method:

```
CoInitializeEx(nullptr, COINIT::COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    Icompte* pcompte;
    
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_compte,nullptr,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_Icompte,(LPVOID*)&pcompte);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) 
    {
        namectrl.GetWindowText(name);
        sernamectrl.GetWindowText(sername);
        emailctrl.GetWindowText(email);
        phonectrl.GetWindowText(phone);
        
        pcompte->put_name(name.AllocSysString());
        pcompte->put_sername(sername.AllocSysString());
        pcompte->put_phone(phone.AllocSysString());
        pcompte->put_phone(email.AllocSysString());
        
        //Managed::showcswindow(name, sername);
        Managed::showcswindow2(pcompte);
    }

    CoUninitialize();
```

wich is found in managed.cpp and i passed the Iunknow to the csahrp method) :

```
 void Managed::showcswindow2(IUnknown* p)
{
    
    services::showwindow2((IntPtr)p);

}
```

in the csharp code :

```
public static void showwindow2(IntPtr p)
        {

            Icompte c = (Icompte)Marshal.GetObjectForIUnknown(p);
            string b =  c.name;
        }
```

the dll is already regestered and included by refrence;

the problem now is that the properties of the object in the csharp code are empty,that string b is null .

Comment: Can't say for sure why properties are empty. From that you successfully cast the object to the interface, it looks like object was passed without issues.  For test purposes you can also try to add test parameterless method  (which will show MessageBox or create file on disk) into the interface and try to call such a method from C# to check if the COM object is passed and accessible. Also check comment from Hans Passant - he says that it is more simple way to solve the problem.

Comment: it worked perfectly actually i forgot to fill the put methods of the properties in the atl project filled thoes and everything works like magic i can fill the object from c++ and retreive the values from c#